# Chrome Resizes Image in div differently

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

What I'm working with now http://pastebin.com/3CSs2tCA

You can paste it in here. http://htmledit.squarefree.com/

In Firefox, if the window is less than 786px wide, the logo gets smaller and keeps its ratio. In Chrome (and my phone), the image keeps its height and gets squished skinny. No idea what to change to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to a kind person on Freenode's #css channel for the answer.

Old code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 786px) {

#logo {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell; 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 75px;
    min-height: 75px;
}
```

changed height to max-height: 100%, and width to auto.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 786px) {

    #logo {
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: table-cell;
        max-height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        min-width: 75px;
        min-height: 75px;
    }
```